# ASP.NET button CommandArgument using <% %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, commandargument

I have the following snippet of code in my .aspx file, I want the button to send the ID to the code behind.

```
<%List<Notes> CommentsList = FindNotes(ParentNote.ID); %>
        <%foreach (var comment in CommentsList) { %>
            <div id="note" class="tierTwo"><p><%: comment.Content %></p><ul><li><%: comment.AddedDate %></li><li>20:29</li><li><%: comment.AddedByName %></li><li><a href="#" onclick="showAddComment(addComment<%:comment.NoteID%>)" class="but">Add comment</a></li></ul> >
                <div id="addComment<%:comment.NoteID%>" class="tierOne" style="display:none">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="commentreplytext" runat="server" rows="4"> </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:HiddenField id="ParentIdReply" value='<%=comment.NoteID%>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandArgument="<%: comment.NoteID%>" OnCommand="Add_Comment" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code behind currently looks like this

```
 protected void Add_Comment(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
 {
    string uniqueNoteID = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
 }
```

The command argument is getting sent to the Add_Comment method but it returns "<%: comment.NoteID%>" rather than the value it represents. This way of retrieving the NoteID value works fine when setting the div id so I don't know why it is causing an issue in the commandArgument.

Comment: why are you doint it like this? you can use repeater and bind data on ,cs page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repeater1">

<ItemTemplate>
<div id="note" class="tierTwo"><p><%# Eval("Content") %></p><ul>
<li><%# Eval("AddedDate") %></li><li>20:29</li>
<li><%# Eval(AddedByName") %></li><li>
<a href="#" onclick='showAddComment(addComment<%#Eval("NoteID")%>)' class="but">Add comment</a></li></ul> 
                <div id='addComment<%# Eval("NoteID") %>' class="tierOne" style="display:none">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="commentreplytext" runat="server" rows="4"> </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:HiddenField id="ParentIdReply" value='<%#Eval("NoteID")%>' runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("NoteID")%>' OnCommand="Add_Comment" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.cs page:

```
repeater1.DataSource = FindNotes(ParentNote.ID);
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get the correct value being send back to my .cs file using the repeater control. I should be able to adapt this approach for my needs. I am not familiar with asp.net applications which may explain my first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use <%%> code blocks in .NET controls. It's to do with the order things get rendered in. You'll have to set the CommandArgument in the code behind when you build the page. You could do that if you built the page using a repeater rather than a for each in the page.